# Indentation issue using sublime text 2

Tags: github, indentation, sublimetext

I have the following problem.

I use ubuntu 12.04 and sublime-text-2 or gedit.

Sometimes i copy/paste something in a haml/ruby file, i indent it at 2 spaces, but when i push it up to github, the indentation is all wrong and not only the part I've copy/pasted. In my editor looks good.

If I open the file with LibreOffice/LeafPad the identation is like on github, but i wanna have it working on ST2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: hmm, not sure. You mean if i once use space, and then tab for indenting? Maybe

Comment: Don't you have config rules or gitattributes files which would change automatically those indentation? As illsutrated in http://gitster.livejournal.com/28862.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have correct indent across the service you should not use hard tabs

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/

You can achieve this functionality in Sublime Text 2 with a tab policy setting:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Configure_sane_tab_and_whitespace_policy_and_other_settings

Also not that you might need to choose new policy for existing files from View > Indentation menu.

You can also mass-convert existing files away from tabs.

With Sublime Text 2:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Converting_existing_files_to_use_spaces_instead_of_tabs

... or batch convert the whole project:

http://miohtama.github.com/vvv/tools/expandtabs.html

Comment: The problem is not hard tabs, the problem is mixing spaces and tabs for indentation.

Comment: The easiest solution for this ia not using tabs at all and thus you cannot mix them with spaces, even accidentally.

Comment: The easiest solution for this is not using spaces at all and thus you cannot mix them with tabs, even accidentally. :)

Comment: s'pose you're in Sublime and just typed the return of a function. Now you want to define another function. When you hit enter, Sublime will put you at same indent as return line -- which you don't want -- when you backspace, it'll move you back to "level" of `def function` line -- or so it looks! but secretly, Sublime put in a tab. You go on to define another function/do something and get a cryptic error. This was the issue I was having