# Strange indenting for Java Eclipse project on Github

Tags: github

Everything is good in Eclipse, indenting is fine. Then I put my code on github
and for some reason the indenting was a mess. I am not sure what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Some screenshots showing what you mean might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those indentation issues are reflected back in your code after a git push to GitHub, you either have:

- a hook removing spaces before tab (as in "[Make git automatically remove trailing whitespace before committing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing)")
- or a filter content driver declared ina `.gitattributes` file (as in "[Can git automatically switch between spaces and tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)")

Those are the two automatic mechanisms that could explain a change during the `git commit`.

---

But if your code looks fine locally *after* the git push, but looks not fine on GitHub, then you must have a combination of space and tabs correctly rendered locally, and rendered differently on GitHub.

As mentioned in "[Indentation issue using sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776009/indentation-issue-using-sublime-text-2)":

> The problem is not hard tabs, the problem is mixing spaces and tabs for indentation.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working in eclipse:

**Eclipse Settings:**

- Preferences : Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
- Create new profile
- Update profile indent settings:

[image]

**Update Existing Java Source:**

- (Toolbar) Source : Correct Indentation
- Check file, you should see all indentations use spaces, not tabs